# Get NVIDIA information in a friendly way?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, programming, interface, monitoring

I'm writing a TaskManager app for Ubuntu, which has as main goal to show me info about my GPU, and I am looking for a way to get information in a programming friendly way, that means, in a way that I can use it in a c++ program without decoding it.

The command `nvidia-smi` shows exactly the information I need, but it's shown in a way I can't write a GUI around it.

So does anyone know a command or a way to use nvidia-smi to show me information as just numbers/strings? So that e.g. when I ask it how much memory a process uses using PID, it just returns the memory usage like this:`123`, without MB or anything behind it.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean like using the -q -x options on nvidia-smi, for xml output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) an example of the output you are talking to and ii) an example of the output you would prefer.

Comment: @ubfan1 EXACTLY! Thanks! If you make your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nvidia-smi program does have a man page:

```
man nvidia-smi
```

which lists options -q and -x for changing the output to XML.

```
nvidia-smi -q -x
```